# How to run GAMS from python?

Tags: python-3.x, subprocess, gams-math

I am trying to run a GAMS file from a python file. I am using vscode on a macbook.

So far, I have been able to open the desired GAMS file from Python using **subprocess**. To do this I have used the following block of code:

```
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['open', "/Users/tk/GAMS/sim.gms"], check=True)
```

However, it just opens the GAMS file but does not execute it. I need to execute the GAMS file and after the GAMS execution is complete, the python program should continue.

How do I do this? Any help is much appreciated.
PS. There is a tutorial on GAMS, but I could not understand it as it seemed too complex to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check in the docs here on how to use GAMS' Python API. There is a "Getting Started" section where you can download all libs needed: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_OVERVIEW.html

I personally have experience using GAMS in a Jupyter Notebook with GAMS Magic, which works pretty well! Check here on how to use it: https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/API_PY_MAGIC.html

Hope it helps!

Answer (score 0):

I've never used gams but after a quick look at [www.gams.com](http://www.gams.com) it sounds like `/Users/tk/GAMS/sim.gms` is not the file to be executed but the input file to be given as argument to the gams executable.

[UG_TutorialQuickstart_RunningTheJob](https://www.gams.com/latest/docs/UG_TutorialQuickstart.html#UG_TutorialQuickstart_RunningTheJob)

So you should try something like :

```py
import subprocess
subprocess.run(['/opt/gams/gams24.3_linux_x64_64_sfx/gams', '/Users/tk/GAMS/sim.gms'], check=True)
```

Notice : there is a GAMS python API which could give you a more portable solution.

Comment: thank you for your suggestions. I tried it but it still opens the GAMS app and stops there without going on to execute the file.