# Running a gams file from python - gams system directory error

Tags: python, gams-math

I would like to run GAMS mdoel from python through the gams python API.

I insalled the API and it works fine:

```
import gams 
print(f'API OK -- Version {gams.__version__}')'''
```

I get:

```
API OK -- Version 45.1.0
```

However when I try to:

```
from gams import GamsWorkspace
ws = GamsWorkspace()
```

I get:

```
GamsException: GAMS System directory  not found or invalid.
```

I tried putting the gams installation path to no avail. The error mentions to use "findthisgams.exe" but I cannot find it.

(gams is intalled and I am able to run it from the GUI)

This is similar to this question: [How to run GAMS from python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75266078/how-to-run-gams-from-python)

still I am stuck.

Comment: findthisgams.exe is in your GAMS system folder, so C:\GAMS\45 by default. However, this is Windows only. Are you using Windows, or do you use a different OS?

Comment: Yes, windows 11, my gams is here: C:\Program Files (x86)\ and it is an older version, not 45.1

Comment: What version is it? In your output you mention GAMS 45.1. Did you mix the API version and the GAMS version? That could cause a problem. If your GAMS is too old, that findthisgams.exe is missing (I am not sure, but I think that must mean, that it is several years old), you might try to add GAMS to the path manually. Then the API should find it.

Comment: Yes my GAMS is very old. C:\Program Files (x86)\GAMS22.6
I installed the API with the command
pip install gamsapi[transfer,magic] --find-links "C:\Program Files (x86)\GAMS22.6\api\python\bdist"

Comment: I don't know why it tells me gams version 45.1. If I open the GUI it tells 22.6. 

I added  C:\Program Files (x86)\GAMS22.6 to the python path manager. 

I tried passing directly the .exe path
gams_systPath = Path("C:\Program Files (x86)\GAMS22.6\gams.exe")
ws = GamsWorkspace(gams_systPath)
(also I do not see an api folder in my GAMS22.6 directory)

Comment: 22.6. is 16 years old. That was way before the Python API was introduced. I doubt that you can make this run (but as a hint: the path to specify should be the folder containing gams.exe, not gams.exe itself). I can just suggest to use the latest GAMS version.

Comment: Thank and ahi, that's beyond me. I just need to launch a GAMS model from python and read the results when it is done. I can call GAMS from command line so I am now trying to figure out how to do it with subprocess, but not getting very far.

Answer (score 1):

Just in case this can be useful to someone, I solved like this. Thanks @Lutz for putting me on the right track.I did not use the API but it does what I wanted it to do.

```
import subprocess

def run_gams(filename, fileoutput):
    try:
        # run gams with the same arguments I would use from the command line
        subprocess.run([r"C:\PATHT\TO\gams.exe", filename, fileoutput], check=True)
    except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
        # Handle any errors that may occur during the GAMS execution
        print(f"Error running GAMS: {e}")
        # Print the error output
        print("Error Output:")
        print(e.stderr)
    

run_gams(r".\PATH\TO\dummy_model.gms", r"Output=.\PATH\TO\dummy_output.txt")
```